# Multiple request/response encoders

Tags: netty

*netty version : 4.0 *

Hi there! I'm planning to use netty to write a client to handle a binary protocol.

The protocol is fairly simple, and it supports several types of requests/responses. Usually a request is initiated and it contains a byte informing what type of request it is (for the server side) but the response does not contain any information. It assumes that the client is waiting for that specific response.

Initially my thought was to build a set of Encoders/Decoders and group them using a ChannelDuplexHandler.

I'm just wondering if the best approach for this is to have several types of pipelines (one for each request/response pair) or to use one single pipeline and then somehow figure on the response what handler would take care of the payload.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

You can either have all of them in one pipeline and just check with instanceof if you can handle it or the next handler should do or you can modify the pipeline on the fly.

Comment: Hi Norman, thanks for the assistance. I believe this should be ok on the outbound route, but for inbound, all I have is the bytes. And on the response I don't have an identifier for the message type. The protocol usually uses the 6th byte on the request to identify the request, but there's no identification on the response. I presume it was assumed it was going to be always used in a request/response traditional blocking scenario. Any suggestion on how to handle this? Regards